# Visual Basic Struct with all windows constants

Tags: vb.net, winapi, constants

Every time I do something that ends up using windows API calls in VB, I always end up having to look up the values for the windows constants.

Does anyone have a file with a class or something for VB that defines all the WIN-API constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of resources for you

- [Pinvoke.Net](http://pinvoke.net): Community driven website which tries to be a reference for Windows API Pinvoke declaration
- [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120): Tool for generating managed PInvoke signatures for native code definitions or the majority of the windows API.

Answer (score 2):

It is already available on your machine, unless you have the Express edition.  Navigate to c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\xxx\include directory.  Where xxx depends on the version of VS you use.  Like v6.0a for VS2008.  The WinUser.h file contains the most common ones you'd use in a Declare statement.  WinError.h has error codes.  Etcetera.  Convert hexadecimal constants, like "0x0123" to VB.NET notation, like "&H123".

This is the 'ultimate and true' source, the Windows SDK declarations that you use an unmanaged program written in C or C++.  Jared showed you the derived ones, they do tend to be flaky in places but that's mostly because there is more than one way to skin a pinvoke cat.  Ymmv.